# Color contrast setting on dataLabels style parameter using Highcharts 5 is not working on some colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

Below is a simple chart. With datalable style settings. Notice the lighter colors are setting to white (when they should set to black) making it an item of complaint with my clients because they can't see them well.

**Here is the code (note the style parameter block):**

```
$(function () {
Highcharts.chart('containera', {
  chart:{ type:'column' },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
  },
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
    colorByPoint: true,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside:true,
        style: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
          color: 'contrast', 
          textShadow: false      
        }
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
      data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
  }]
  });
});
```

**Here is the Fiddle (also in the fiddle it is ignoring the textshadow:false):**

http://jsfiddle.net/franktudor/98Ldn972/

**Here is the image (note the green and orange):**
[image]

What are the thresholds for contrast? Can they be altered as a global? Because that would be handy. I have 200 charts would like to fix what the highcharts engine considers light and dark colors for contrast labels globally if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current contrast function looks like this:

```
    /**
     * Returns white for dark colors and black for bright colors.
     *
     * @param {ColorString} rgba - The color to get the contrast for.
     * @returns {string} The contrast color, either `#000000` or `#FFFFFF`.
     */
    getContrast: function(rgba) {
        rgba = color(rgba).rgba;
        return rgba[0] + rgba[1] + rgba[2] > 2 * 255 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
    },
```

You could extend highcharts and override that function to control the contrast however you'd like.  I changed the test from `rgba[0] + rgba[1] + rgba[2] > 2 * 255` to  `rgba[0] + rgba[1] + rgba[2] > 500` and it solves your stated problem.  But, there is probably some better color logic you could apply.

```
  // override getContrast function
  (function(H) {
    H.Renderer.prototype.getContrast = function(rgba) {
      rgba = H.Color(rgba).rgba;
      return rgba[0] + rgba[1] + rgba[2] > 500 ? '#000000' : '#FFFFFF';
    };
  }(Highcharts));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98Ldn972/3/

Edit:
Just noticed the textShadow part of the question.  I think what you want to remove is the textOutline

```
style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: "contrast",
    textOutline: false
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/98Ldn972/4/

Comment: You know...You are really good at the nuanced stuff (this is the second time you helped me) (:  Thanks!!!

Comment: Oh and bonus +1 for the textOutline tip

Comment: Glad to help.  These are the sorts of questions I love.